# How can I get an Object that has a key value of 0?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a object but the key value is 0 so I keep getting an error when I try to access it.

```
locations: Object
  0: Object
     1: Object
```

I've tried doing `locations["0"]` and `locations.0` but none of those work. I just get `undefined` when I try to see the object in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(locations)` and post the result so we can see?

Comment: ... even better `console.log(JSON.stringify(locations))`. Will be easier to see what's going on

Comment: I figured it out. It was something unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locations.0` is a syntax error, as only valid identifiers can follow the dot. Both `locations["0"]` and `locations[0]` should work equally well. If they do not display the value you expect, make sure there is no change to the object; note that the default console printing method is not synchronous unless you print a string (i.e. if you're doing `console.log(locations); locations[0] = "foo"`, you will likely see `0: "foo"` in your console output).